# How to replace element of xml using xdocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

example xml:

```
<string-name>
    <given-name>Sisgon</given-name>
</string-name>
```

changes of xml element:

```
<string-name>
    <surname>Sisgon</surname>
</string-name>
```

I want to change the given-name tag to surname without changing the inner text.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you already try something and if so please add your code and specific error/problem to your question. If you need some more guidelines on how to improve your question you can refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't change the node name and must create a new XElement.  So use following : List<XElement> names = doc.Descendents("given-name).ToList(); foreach(XElement name in names){ name.ReplaceWith(new XElement("surname", (string)name));}

Comment: [`XElement.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Name) is mutable: *`public System.Xml.Linq.XName Name { get; set; }`*.  So you can just rename the element.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(content);
var event_nodes = xmlDoc.Descendants("given-name");
foreach(var node in event_nodes)
{
    node.Name = "surname";
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xmlDoc.ToString());
```

To add an attribute add the following in the for each:

```
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("Name","value");
node.Add(attribute)
```

Comment: how do i add the attribute, for example my given-name has attribute first.

Comment: thanks bro I try this code:var series = xdocc.Descendants("given-name").Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("first").Value ==""); to get the attribute